# Service.startForeground() not allowed when service restarts

Tags: android, service, crash

I'm working on a music player app targeting Android SDK 31. To make the song keep playing when the app is in the background, I created a service and I start it this way:

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, Intent(context, MyService.class))
```

And then, in the service class, I create a notification on the onStartCommand function:

```
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MUSIC_CHANNEL)
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentIntent(mediaSessionController.mediaSession!.controller!.sessionActivity)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setForegroundServiceBehavior(FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
            .setOngoing(true)

        startForeground(SERVICE_ID, notification)
        return START_STICKY
    }
```

(I update the notification with the media info later)

I'm returning `START_STICKY` because the [Android documentation says it is the ideal mode for services like music players](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#START_REDELIVER_INTENT).

When the user pauses the song, I call

```
stopForeground(false)
```

So the notification can be dismiss by the user (like any music player).

The problem is: when the app is closing (dismissed by the user), MyService's `onDestroy()` will be called and then, because it is in  `START_STICKY` mode (I think), the service will be immediately recreated. Because the app is on background, it crashes:

`Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false`

There is a comment on the `START_STICKY` Android code, explaining that this restriction doesn't apply to service restarts, witch is my case, isn't?

```
 * <p>Since Android version {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#S}, apps
 * targeting {@link Build.VERSION_CODES#S} or above are disallowed
 * to start a foreground service from the background, but the restriction
 * doesn't impact <em>restarts</em> of a sticky foreground service. However,
 * when apps start a sticky foreground service from the background,
 * the same restriction still applies.
 */
public static final int START_STICKY = 1;
```

In my understanding, the app shouln'd crash in this situation. Did I get enything wrong?

I tried to detect when the service is created or restarted, by passing an `action` on its intent. I can detect that the service is being restarted by checking if this `action` is `NULL`. If it is, I do not call `startForeground()`.  It seams that worked, but it looks more like a workaround rather an ideal implementation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would recommend simply not using `START_STICKY`. If the music is paused and your service is destroyed, you do not need the service to be recreated automatically -- you can do that if and when the user elects to play music again.

Comment: I agree with you but it is still confusing. It seems that the Android Documentation is leading my app to crash 

Comment: That advice has been in the docs for over a decade, and I have never agreed with it. There are two possibilities for what happens when the service gets restarted: the music restarts, or it does not. If the music restarts, that means that the phone will start playing music at some random time based on when the OS decides to restart the service. If the music does not restart... then why do you need the service? Neither path seems like it is what the user would want.